# Android Market shows "This item is not compatible with your device"

Tags: android, google-play

I just published an application in android market. When i tried to download my application from market in Samsung galaxy S II and some micromax devices, I couldn't find the application. When i tried to install from web market it says " This item is not compatible with your device". My application doesnot require any uses-permission. Please help me out.

Here is the manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <application
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/rti_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="4" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" >
    </supports-screens>

</manifest>
```

Comment: remove the android:targetSdkVersion="4" http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target

Comment: @Padma Kumar Probably you can add it as an answer

Comment: @Richie hay thanks Richie Rich:-)

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the `android:targetDdk version="4"` or change it with the version your device is compatible with

Comment: I think galaxy S II has api > 4

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the Market didn't give you an error message when you uploaded your apk.

Your package name "com.sample" is so generic, it is bound to have been taken by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is the screen size.

See these two sites that explain how to support all the screen sizes:

[Market-Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html)

[Supports Screens Element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your manifest file

```
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Move your <uses-sdk> block up above <application>.  Delete <supports-screens> entirely, unless there is a screen size that your application does *not* support.