# Android app not comptible but listed to be compatible

Tags: android, compatibility, publish

I developed an Android app and released it on Google Play yesterday. The only problem is that I can't install the applicatien from the market on my own phone (HTC DESIRE/BRAVO). It is listed to be compatible with htc desire  but when I try to download it it says it isn't. 
I rooted my phone and have BCM ICS 4.0.3 CM9 installed. Could this cause the issue? How can I make it compatible? Thanks

Edit: Is it possible to adjust something in the code?

Comment: Probably the problem is the screen size.

See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869651/android-market-shows-this-item-is-not-compatible-with-your-device/10385298#10385298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a custom rom can make apps appear to be incompatible even when they are. A common issue is when it uses a non standard screen density setting in an attempt to gain more screen real estate.

If you do have a modified density, you could try setting it back to the default for your device. http://wccftech.com/article/increase-screen-dpi/